# Unable to update database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a the following code for inputing data in a database..i specifically echoed the values to see whether they have correct values or not...they have correct values but the values i get in the database are totally different.

Here is my code

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("sm_sample");
    $source=$_POST['source'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $complaint=$_POST['complaint'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    echo $source.$username.$location.$category.$complaint.$status.$date;

    $sql="INSERT INTO sample VALUES(ID=NULL,source='$source',username=
            '$username', location='$location', category='$category',complaint=
            '$complaint',date='$date',status='$status')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='usercom1.php'>View result</a>";
    mysql_close($con)
    ?>
```

the values i get in the database r like this:
List data from mysql

```
Source Username  Location   Category Complaint     Date      Status     Update 
 0     Singapore                0    0000-00-00    Pending      Edit
```

Comment: Give us the `var_dump` or `print_r` of `$_POST` and the corresponding MySQL row

Comment: _"i specifically echoed the values to see whether they have correct values or not"_ That's great. But then you turn to ask us what's wrong with your code. But we're **unable** to see your values! So, how we are supposed to tell what's wrong with your results?!

Comment: Please, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Your code is open to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @rolando: i dont think $_post has a problem coz i specifically echoed to check that n they show correct values

Comment: @vedant OMG it is not for you. It is for US, so we'll be able to help you. Wouild you PLEASE give us the var_dump or print_r of $_POST and the corresponding MySQL row?

Comment: @markus: i know but i just have to code n pass it to the testing team...they will take care of the rest :)

Comment: Testing team? There are some people in the world who would test *this*? Is it sort of punishment?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `sample`(`ID`,`source`,`username`, `location`,`category`,`complaint`,`date`,`status`) 
      VALUES (0, '$source','$username','$location','$category','$complaint','$date','$status')";
```

later edit ... you are using wrong mysql_query and connection syntax

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('database connection?');
mysql_select_db("sm_sample", $con) or die('wrong database?');
// and for $_POST you sould use mysql_real_escape_string
$source = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['source']);
// ........................................
$sql="INSERT INTO `sample`(`ID`,`source`,`username`, `location`,`category`,`complaint`,`date`,`status`) 
      VALUES (0, '$source','$username','$location','$category','$complaint','$date','$status')";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: '.mysql_error().': '.mysql_errno());
// ........................................
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: why downvote? Just for fun or you don;t have anything to do ?

Comment: is it necesary??coz my previous codes used to work even without that

Comment: you should always use correct syntax-es as you will never know when deprecated/wrong syntax will disappear/not work anymore ...

Comment: you are free to share your opinion as a comment, not answer.

Comment: You just didn't answer *the question* even a little bit.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I don't know what did you understand from the question but he said he is unable to insert into database and I pointed his errors, where should start from, and I'm pretty much sure my answer will work. Your comment is pretty odd assuming he was saying the values in the ``$_POST`` are correct but in database he gets default values.

Comment: you didn't read the question. and you know no sql. he has his insert work, as he said: `the values i get in the database`. So, it's something wrong with values, not insert. And the syntax he's using is perfectly valid one. try to improve both your knowledge and attention

Comment: ok mister smart, what is the question? He didn't wrote a question, maybe that were the values he inserted into db. I'm using mysql database over 12 years now. If you say I don't know sql because I never accepted other "middle" sollutions other than [MySQL Syntax-es](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: @mihai lorga:thnx man..my script is working now..thnx for ur quick response

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      echo ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("sm_sample",$con);
    $source=$_POST['source'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $complaint=$_POST['complaint'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    echo $source.$username.$location.$category.$complaint.$status.$date;

    $sql="INSERT INTO sample ('source','username','location','category','complaint','status') VALUES('$source','$username','location','category','complaint','status' )";
    if (!mysql_query($sql))
      {
        echo ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='usercom1.php'>View result</a>";
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

First thing you do not have to add id if it is auto increment and date if it uses current timestamp and one more thing that never use `die();` , use `echo` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You should provide only VALUES of data with no column names:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sample VALUES(ID, '$source', '$username', '$location', '$category', '$complaint', '$date', '$status')";
```

Also if you have only one DB connection you can not to define $con variable in mysql_query(). Like this: `mysql_query($sql)`.

Comment: @vedant You should check out the documentation about [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert.html) as webbandit is right about this.

Comment: @webbandit i didnt get the $con part you said...what shud i do?

Comment: Making assumptions about the order of columns is risky. If you don't want a mismatch between two lists, use the `INSERT INTO ... SET col = value, col = value` syntax.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the following line:

```
<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO sample VALUES(ID=NULL,source='$source',username='$username', location='$location', category='$category',complaint=
'$complaint',date='$date',status='$status')";
?>
```

If you check the result in the database, you'll see that the values are getting in the wrong order, use this instead:

```
<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO sample(ID, source, username, location, category, complaint, date, status)  VALUES(NULL, '$source', '$username', '$location', '$category', '$complaint','$date','$status')";
?>
```

PLEASE read what `Albireo` posted in his comment. Your code is extremely vulnerable.